# Dynamic row background datagrid Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, background-color

I have a DataGrid control bound to an ItemsSource. My ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection and it and I always insert my items ordered on it. I need to set the background of each row of the DataGrid depending on the value and its index on the DataGrid.
Do you know any way to do that?
Note: the ObservableCollection will be updated by another thread, so when it updates, I have to update the background color of the grid.

I've seen some people doing things similar using a converter, but all my business logic is in the ViewModel and I need to get values from it to discover wich color will be the background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a LoadingRow event handler to your DataGrid, and then setup a binding to each row's Background property on their respective item's view model property:

XAML DataGrid:

```
<data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FooBars}" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow" >
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FOO" Binding="{Binding Foo}" Width="200" />
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="BAR" Binding="{Binding Bar}" Width="60"/>
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void packetsDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Binding backgroundBinding = new Binding("FooBarItemBackground");
    backgroundBinding.Source = e.Row.DataContext;
    e.Row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty, backgroundBinding);
}
```

Comment: There's a problem... for example: when I new row is added, I have to update every row below have to update its background.

Comment: No problem :) When a new row is added that could trigger an event on your view model to update the background color property of each item. Since it's data bound you wouldn't have to rebind the grid or anything.

Comment: This sounds like the way I am using also it should be the way to go